# popping shoulders

Tags: weightlifting, shoulders, health-risk

Yesterday during my workout (chest, shoulder, triceps) something really odd happened, while doing incline bench press, one of my shoulders *"popped"* it didn't hurt, I was able to finish my reps. Then it popped again while doing dips, no pain, just an odd feeling. Today I'm not aching or anything but I'm concerned I might be pushing my shoulders to the limit and raising the risk of an actual injury.

Are these type of events normal? I've been working out for a while, but I've never heard/felt my shoulder pop before.

PS It was the left shoulder, and I'm left-handed, I don't know if that's a relevant detail.

Comment: In the absence of pain, some snapping and popping my be normal.  But, it's dependent upon your age, exercise experience and any previous injuries.

Comment: No injury history, 26, exercised the entirety of 2014, for different reasons dropped it from jan - may 2015, been actively working out since then... @rrirower

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to preface this response with "I am not a health professional." In fact, I am merely a college student who enjoys weightlifting. When I played football in high school I had the same exact problem with my left shoulder (I am right handed, however). I experienced the same symptoms as you: popping joints with little-to-no pain while working out and when on the field making tackles.

I had some x-rays done, and the doctors weren't able to identify anything serious. I later went to a specialist, and he told me that I had **loose tendons.** By adding shoulder workouts to all of my workouts, I was able to strengthen the surrounding muscles and tendons. I managed to build up the tissue around my joint, keeping the shoulder in place. After a few months of these specialized workouts, **the problem subsided.**

Some good workouts:

- http://www.active.com/fitness/articles/3-exercises-to-strengthen-the-shoulders - some starting points, feel free to get creative
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tTbuX7IVy-Q - I did these almost every day
- https://youtu.be/PoD-PBOiN_Q?t=2m50s - I used one of these (motion demonstrated in this video) except I brought my arms out to the side, similar to a fly.

Comment: Could you edit your answer adding these specialized shoulder workouts?

Comment: Does that help you?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter they're just links, I'm writing them down in a file. Thanks

Comment: If you're satisfied with my response, feel free to mark your question answered :)

Comment: I plan to, I'm giving my question til next morning since I barely posted it today

Comment: Can you add some detail on the exercises you, specifically, found useful, so that in the event that your links break in the future your answer is still fully useful.

Comment: Those were the exercises I found useful. I tried to find videos explaining them because I think they do a better job than I would.